# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError In ListView

Tags: android, listview, bitmap, out-of-memory, android-arrayadapter

i have a problem with listView and images, when set images in a moment make me a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError, this is my implementation of the ArrayAdapter in getview

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag
        if(convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_list_item, parent, false);
            viewHolder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Icon);
            viewHolder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nombreCategoriaTextView);
            viewHolder.name.setText(categories.getCategories(position).getName());
            try {
                DataBaseImageManager manager = new DataBaseImageManager(context);
                Bitmap mIcon11 = manager.getListByName(categories.getCategories(position).getURLImage());
                if (mIcon11 == null)
                    new DownloadImageTask(viewHolder.image, context)
                            .execute(categories.getCategories(position).getURLImage());
                else {
                    (viewHolder.image).setImageBitmap(mIcon11);
                }
            }catch (Exception e){}
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        return convertView;
    }
```

i am putting my images in sqlIte and i decodified the bitmap from ByteArray the implementation is the next

```
public Bitmap getListByName(String name) {
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        try {
            DataSource.open();
            List<DatosImage> datos = DataSource.obtenerRegistros(name);
            for (DatosImage dato : datos) {
                 bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(dato.getValue(), 0, dato.getValue().length);
            }
            DataSource.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bmp;
    }
```

which can be the soulution from my problem or whats is worng with my code?

```
the error is the nextFATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-07 12:31:24.490 19660-19660/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: mx.com.sithec.cic, PID: 19660
11-07 12:31:24.490 19660-19660/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
11-07 12:31:24.490 19660-19660/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeByteArray(Native Method)
11-07 12:31:24.490 19660-19660/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:500)
11-07 12:31:24.490 19660-19660/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:523)
11-07 12:31:24.490 19660-19660/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at mx.com.sithec.cic.ImageHelper.DataBaseImageManager.getListByName(DataBaseImageManager.java:31)
11-07 12:31:24.490 19660-19660/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at mx.com.sithec.cic.Adapters.CompanyAdapter.getView(CompanyAdapter.java:102)
11-07 12:31:24.490 19660-19660/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2283)
11-07 12:31:24.490 19660-19660/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
11-07 12:31:24.490 19660-19660/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.fillUp(ListView.java:725)
11-07 12:31:24.490 19660-19660/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:664)
11-07 12:31:24.490 19660-19660/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5423)
11-07 12:31:24.490 19660-19660/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4534)
11-07 12:31:24.490 19660-19660/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
11-07 12:31:24.490 19660-19660/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
11-07 12:31:24.490 19660-19660/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
11-07 12:31:24.490 19660-19660/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
11-07 12:31:24.490 19660-19660/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-07 12:31:24.490 19660-19660/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-07 12:31:24.490 19660-19660/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-07 12:31:24.490 19660-19660/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5070)
11-07 12:31:24.490 19660-19660/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-07 12:31:24.490 19660-19660/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-07 12:31:24.490 19660-19660/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
11-07 12:31:24.490 19660-19660/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
11-07 12:31:24.490 19660-19660/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for loop in getListByName() seems odd. You might be creating multiple bitmaps (that alone could cause the OutOfMemoryError exception if you have many bitmaps in a single run) but are only returning one.

What you should probably do is something like:

```
public Bitmap getListByName(String name) {
    try {
        DataSource.open();
        List<DatosImage> datos = DataSource.obtenerRegistros(name);
        for (DatosImage dato : datos) {
             Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(dato.getValue(), 0, dato.getValue().length);
             if (bmp != null) {
                 DataSource.close();
                 return bmp;
             }
        }
        DataSource.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be in fact, that you are creating Bitmap object for each row in a list. It is ver memory expensive operation, especially if bitmaps are big and numerous.

I think the easiest way for coping with this issue would be to simply use one of libraries that are already there for such cases (loading images from URL to image view). Let me give you some examples

## [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Very easy to use, just add it to gour build.gradle

`compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'`

And then within your code:

`Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);`

If you still want to cache your images in DB, you can using Picasso for that:

```
Picasso.with(this).load("url").into(new Target()
{
    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from)
    {
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        //Code for DB save
    }
    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable)
    {
        image.setImageDrawable(errorDrawable);
    }
    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable)
    {
        image.setImageDrawable(placeHolderDrawable);
    }
});
```

You might also want to take a look at [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! its a great tool